# Domain joined user can see all users and groups on the domain?

Tags: active-directory

Why a normal domain user on a domain joined Computer can see all users and groups on the domain through win32_account Class? Can this be prevented?

Answer (score 0):

This is by Msft default design. "Authenticated Users" are allowed to read Azure AD objects (in general, some specific attributes excepted).

You can change this in AD object rights, but Msft is usually not recommending this, at least for the domain root. You may try it with the object properties of a Ou and move users below this.
You can edit these rights in "ActiveDirectory Users and Computers":

- right click OU
- select "Properties"
- select Tab "Security"
- remove "Read" from "Authenticated Users"

Or

- create a User Group for selected users you want to prevent from browsing
- add this group to Security and add "Deny" for "Read"